# Why are 3D cube faces distorted?

Tags: html, css

I'm designing a rotating cube logo for my portfolio site. After trying all night, for some reason my 3D cube logo is no longer a cube. Two problems:

1. The shape of the cube is distorted. The `.front` div is larger than all the other divs for the cube. I can't see why this is happening.
2. When `.container` div's animation is commented out, you'll notice the viewer position is head on. I need the view position to be more 'isometric', like the viewer is looking at the edge of the cube from above. I've tried to rotate the Z- and Y-axis of the `.container` div to achieve this but no luck so far. Un-comment the `background-color: pink;` on the `.container` div to see this.
3. I have a feeling the above problems are to do with the `perspective` property. I'm not sure how to calculate the correct amount of perspective here, and this could be my problem.

Here's my [CodePen link](https://codepen.io/simonrevill/pen/Rqgzyq?editors=1100).

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="cube">
      <div class="front"><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/cube-logo/logo.png" alt="logo"></div>
      <div class="back"><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/cube-logo/logo.png" alt="logo"></div>
      <div class="left"><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/cube-logo/logo.png" alt="logo"></div>
      <div class="right"><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/cube-logo/logo.png" alt="logo"></div>
      <div class="top"><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/cube-logo/logo.png" alt="logo"></div>
      <div class="bottom"><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/cube-logo/logo.png" alt="logo"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html {
  background: #666;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -200px;
  margin-top: -200px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
/*   background-color: pink; */
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  perspective: 1000px;
  animation: rotate 2000ms linear infinite;
}

.cube {
/*  background-color: blue; */
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -100px;
 margin-top: -100px;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.cube div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-size: cover;
}

.cube img {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}

.front {
  transform: translateZ(100px);
}

.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(100px);
}

.left {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
}

.right {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(100px);
}

.top {
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(100px);
}

.bottom {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: it's the perspective that is creating the issue, not sure if you need it. Remove it and the issue will get fixed

Comment: Okay thanks but how do I change the view? Don't I need perspective to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are an issue because you rotate the container and its perspective as well.

you want a perspective on the cube, you have to set the `perspective` property on `body` element (or any kind of container of your animation that is not animated itself) and avoid to set it on the animated element. Actually, moving the element that is set by a `perspective` value will move this 3D element inside a 2D view – its own parent element. That causes the weird cube rendering on your exemple.

Also, if you want to control the perpective origin, you can use [perspective-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective-origin) that lets you determine the position at which the viewer is looking. Associated with `perspective` property, you will be able to control the whole rendered scene.

So, the result will change with following code:

```css
html { background: #666; }

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  perspective: 900px;
  perspective-origin: bottom;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -200px;
  margin-top: -200px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: rotate 2000ms linear infinite;
}

.cube {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -100px;
 margin-top: -100px;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.cube div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-size: cover;
}

.cube img { 
  width: 100%; 
}

.front { transform: translateZ(100px); }
.back { transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(100px); }
.left { transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(100px); }
.right { transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(100px); }
.top { transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(100px); }
.bottom { transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px); }

@keyframes rotate {
  to { transform: rotateY(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="cube">
      <div class="front"><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/cube-logo/logo.png" alt="logo"></div>
      <div class="back"><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/cube-logo/logo.png" alt="logo"></div>
      <div class="left"><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/cube-logo/logo.png" alt="logo"></div>
      <div class="right"><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/cube-logo/logo.png" alt="logo"></div>
      <div class="top"><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/cube-logo/logo.png" alt="logo"></div>
      <div class="bottom"><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/cube-logo/logo.png" alt="logo"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes this makes sense. But why now am I viewing the cube from above? I can see the top of the cube. Please check out the pen, I’ve updated it: https://codepen.io/simonrevill/pen/Rqgzyq?editors=1100

Comment: Yes you can modify the perspective-origin in order to change the view. I just updated my answer

Comment: `perspective-origin: bottom;` seems to meet your needs here

Comment: Tried that, and thanks. Instead `perspective: top` and `perspective: 2000` seems to have worked well. I only wish I understood how to calculate the perspective value mathematically!

Comment: Thinking about it some more, it seems the `perspective` property has to be adjusted to your own preference.

Comment: Good to hear :) It depends on your need, the perspective value is a distance point of view. Smaller the distance is, taller the rendering scene will be. If you are distant of 1meter from a building, the perspective will be huge, but if you are distant of 1Km, the perspective will be flat.

Comment: Yes, it depends on your preference !

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking. I did try to imagine it in real life. Thanks for your help :-)